# Is there a discrete version of the residue theorem?

Tags: residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula, integer-lattices

Consider the integral:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+iz)}\frac{1}{(y+iz)} dz = \frac{-2\pi}{|x-y|} $$

if $xy<0$ and zero otherwise. i.e. it is only non-zero if $x$ and $y$ are different sides of the complex axis.

Are there any similar residue-like identities but instead of integrating a contour on the complex plane, summing over values on a lattice? e.g. a discrete version of the above identity? If we replace the integral with a sum in the above equation it doesn't work but is there anything similar?

Comment: Similar in what way? There are continuous parameters in the integral, and to me, the remarkable thing is that the integral is 0 for certain ranges of the parameter, but not always 0. Is this the phenomenon you are looking for in a sum?

Comment: @User yes exactly.

Comment: Fourier series can definitely exhibit behavior like this.